# Inventory File - Children Groups - In Ansible

Tags: mongodb, deployment, ansible

Simple question. I am trying to deploy MongoDB in Ansible, and I have a list of 20 replica sets - 40 replication servers with 1 arbiter for each set - in my inventory (/ansible/hosts) file. The way I have my `rep_sets:children` right now doesn't work, and I am assuming it is because you can list hostnames using the `[x:y]` context, but not actual groups.

```
# The site wide list of mongodb servers

# Mongo Replica Servers
[rep_servers]
mrep[1:40]

# Mongo Query Routers
[query_routers]
mqr[1:3]

# Mongo Config Servers
[config_servers]
mcfg[1:3]

# Mongo Arbiter Servers
[arb_servers]
marb[1:5]

# All the replica sets (1-20)
[rs1]
mrep1
mrep21

.
.
.

[rs20]
mrep20
mrep40

[rep_sets:children]
rs[1:20]
```

So, is there a way to list them all as children without having to write out each one under the `rep_sets:children` group that I am simply just missing?

Comment: Could you just point it to a variable that loops through all hosts in a jinja2 file in the group_vars directory? I understand it's not difficult to just list all 20 replica set groups under the children, but I am just trying to make it look cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just for a cleaner look, you may try the [yaml inventory plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/plugins/inventory/yaml.html).

This makes it easier to build that kind of inventory.